# unboundをwindowsでインストールした際の設定

Tags: windows

unboundをインストールサイトからインストールした時の設定ファイル、設定項目を教えて欲しいです。
windowsで設定したいです。

どこもLinuxでのインストールのことばかり書いてあるので、/etc/unbound/unbound.confを設定してくださいになっていますが、見当たりません。

C/Program File/Unbound配下にインストールしたもの全てがあります。
service.confかexample.confしかありません。

Comment: ファイルは`service.conf`で良さそうです[Config Unbound On Windows](https://www.quakemachinex.com/blog/wp-content/plugins/clean-archives-reloaded/ajax-single.php?postid=170), [Windows 10 Optimization Guide suggestion - Unbound DNS server?](https://www.tenforums.com/network-sharing/45988-windows-10-optimization-guide-suggestion-unbound-dns-server.html), [Manual for Unbound on Windows](https://nlnetlabs.nl/documentation/unbound/unbound-windows-manual-02.pdf), [Does not work on Windows 10...](https://github.com/NLnetLabs/unbound/issues/381), [Unbound by NLnet Labs](https://unbound.docs.nlnetlabs.nl/en/latest/)

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UnboundをWindowsにインストーラーや`unbound-service-install.exe`でサービスとしてインストールすると、サービス起動の引数において設定ファイルが指定されています。

例えば私の環境ではその実行ファイルのパスは

```
"C:\tools\Unbound\unbound.exe" -c "C:\tools\Unbound\service.conf" -w service
```

となっています。つまり、この`service.conf`がWindowsサービスとしての起動時に読み込まれる設定ファイルになります。
設定項目については原則Linux環境等と変わりはありません。(少し異なる部分もあるかもしれませんが、デフォルトのservice.confにそのあたりの説明はあるでしょう)

Comment: 解決しました！ありがとうございました(⋆ᵕᴗᵕ⋆)